# AWS SDK - Does AmazonS3ClientBuilder instance expires?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the JAVA AWS SDK to upload thousands of images to my s3 bucket.

I created a static type AmazonS3 variable to connect to the bucket. I'm uploading thousands of images and this is taking more than 24 hours to upload.

As I'm using a static Object i just connect to the bucket once and the Threads make the upload. I would like to know if the session can expirates during this process and if the correct way would be to connect every time before send the image.

This is how I instanciated it:

```html
return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `AmazonS3` object you get from the builder (which is an instance of `AmazonS3Client`) does not maintain a persistent connection to S3. Every action you make with it (like `putObject` or `deleteObject`) is a separate HTTP request, and each action is signed with the credentials you provide.

So how long the client is valid for depends on what type of credentials you're wrapping with `AWSStaticCredentialsProvider`.

1. If you're passing a `BasicAWSCredentials(String accessKey, String secretKey)` with permanent, non-expiring Access and Secret keys, then you can use the `AmazonS3` object for as long as you wanted.
2. If your `AWSStaticCredentialsProvider` is actually wrapping a `BasicSessionCredentials` object, then those credentials do eventually expire, as session credentials are temporary (session credentials are valid for anywhere between 15 minutes - 36 hours).

Comment: Thanks! I'm using BasicAWSCredentials(String accessKey, String secretKey), But I didn't find any option at IAM Management Console to set my accessKey and secretKey as non-expiring.

Comment: @Andre if you just create the key in the IAM console, it doesn't expire. The temporary credentials are all generated via another mechanism.